# Python print !!python/object when class is called

Tags: python

I'm facing a weird issue when I run a script. Basically, I just want to convert json to yaml and put the result in a file. When I run the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from CP import test
import json, yaml

dump_value = {"objects": [{"name": "home_pc","ipv4": "1.1.1.1"},{"name": "home_switch","ipv4": "1.1.1.10"},{"name": "dns_server","ipv4": "8.8.8.8"}]}

# Initialize dict
cpdb = test.db_utils()

cpdb.create_list("hosts")
for h in dump_value['objects']:
    cpdb.add_listdata("hosts", json.dumps({"name": h['name'], "ipv4": h['ipv4']}))

print(yaml.dump(cpdb, indent=2, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))
```

The output is:

```
!!python/object:CP.test.db_utils
data:
  top:
    hosts:
    - '{"name": "home_pc", "ipv4": "1.1.1.1"}'
    - '{"name": "home_switch", "ipv4": "1.1.1.10"}'
    - '{"name": "dns_server", "ipv4": "8.8.8.8"}'
```

Here's the content of test.py in CP:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class db_utils:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.data['top'] = {}

    def create_list(self, key): self.data['top'][key] = []
    def add_data(self, key, value): self.data['top'][key] = value
    def add_listdata(self, key, value): self.data['top'][key].append(value)
```

I expected the following output:

```
top:
  hosts:
  - '{"name": "home_pc", "ipv4": "1.1.1.1"}'
  - '{"name": "home_switch", "ipv4": "1.1.1.10"}'
  - '{"name": "dns_server", "ipv4": "8.8.8.8"}'
```

I use python 3.8.3. I already tried the code on another computer (thought maybe I broke something) but same result on python 3.9.1.

I think it may be related to the class db_utils in test.py, but I can't find what's wrong.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the output you see is that you are dumping the `prdb` object you have created directly, and its data structure contains a top level dictionary named `data`.

The other issue, the first line you're seeing that specifies the type of the object you are dumping, appears for a similar reason.  It's there because you are not dumping a standard Python structure, but rather an arbitrary class instance.  Yaml dumps that header to indicate the class being dumped so that you'll have some chance of reconstituting it when you read the YAML file.

To fix both of these problems, you should extract just the raw data structure you want represented by the YAML and dump that.  To do that, you can add a method to your `db_utils` object that returns the contents of its `data` attribute.  Then you can dump that.  Here's the code with a `get_data` method added and used (and your two files collapsed into one for my convenience):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json, yaml

class db_utils:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.data['top'] = {}

    def create_list(self, key): self.data['top'][key] = []

    def add_data(self, key, value): self.data['top'][key] = value

    def add_listdata(self, key, value): self.data['top'][key].append(value)

    def get_data(self): return self.data

dump_value = {"objects": [{"name": "home_pc","ipv4": "1.1.1.1"},{"name": "home_switch","ipv4": "1.1.1.10"},{"name": "dns_server","ipv4": "8.8.8.8"}]}

# Initialize dict
cpdb = db_utils()

cpdb.create_list("hosts")
for h in dump_value['objects']:
    cpdb.add_listdata("hosts", json.dumps({"name": h['name'], "ipv4": h['ipv4']}))

print(yaml.dump(cpdb.get_data(), indent=2, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))
```

Result:

```
top:
  hosts:
  - '{"name": "home_pc", "ipv4": "1.1.1.1"}'
  - '{"name": "home_switch", "ipv4": "1.1.1.10"}'
  - '{"name": "dns_server", "ipv4": "8.8.8.8"}'
```

You don't really even have to add the extra method to `db_utils`.  You can just grab the `data` attribute out of the object directly.  I think it's cleaner to add a method to get at the internal data, but if you wanted a more minimal change (5 added characters), just change the final line of your code to this:

```
print(yaml.dump(cpdb.data, indent=2, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False))
```

The result you get will be the same.